# Why does my algorithm not check the last element of the linkedlist?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I made a small system which takes a seatCount to fill a cinema with a certain amount of seats (no rows). Now I made a method which fills the seats and returns a Map, the map returns at what position a certain amount of seats are free (for instance 3-2 means there are two seats next to eachother beginning at place 3.

This works pretty well but if for example I say there are 5 seats maximum and seat 5 is free, the method does not return it to the map.

Here is the code used:

Object Seat

```
public class Seat {
    public Integer availability;
    public Integer seatNumber;

    public boolean IsFree() {
        if(availability == 0){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{ " + seatNumber + ", free: " + IsFree() + " } ";
    }
}
```

This method creates a LinkedList and fills the availibility with '1' (taken) or '0' (available) via the giveRandomAvailability() method

```
static LinkedList fillList(int seats){

    LinkedList<Seat> list = new LinkedList<Seat>();
    seats = seatCount;

    for(int i = 0; i < seats; i++){
        Seat seat = new Seat();
        seat.availability = giveRandomAvailability();
        seat.seatNumber = (i + 1);
        list.add(seat);
    }

    return list;
}
```

This is the method which does not work correctly, it should fill the map with the available seats, but when the last element is available, it does not map is.
Here is an example output:

```
[{ 1, free: true } , { 2, free: true } , { 3, free: false } , { 4, free: true } , { 5, free: true } ]
{1=2}
```

You can see that the first part is handled well but it should also contain 4 = 2.

The method:

```
static Map fillSeats(){
    int n = 3;
    LinkedList<Seat> newList = fillList(seatCount);
    int consecutiveLength = 0; // Consecutive free seats length
    int index = 0;
    int startIndex = -1; // Store the start of consecutive free seats
    System.out.println(newList.toString());
    Map<Integer, Integer> consecutiveMap = new HashMap<>(); // Store startIndex -> length

    for (Seat seat : newList) {
        if (seat.IsFree()) {
            if (startIndex < 0) {
                startIndex = index;
            }
            consecutiveLength ++;
        } else {
            consecutiveMap.put(startIndex + 1, consecutiveLength);
            if (consecutiveLength == n) {
                // Found, do something here
            }
            // Reset
            startIndex = -1;
            consecutiveLength = 0;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return consecutiveMap;
}
```

I can not find the issue here, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not related to my answer below, but a number of code improvement tips: I do not think these methods need to be static. `IsFree` should start with a lowercase letter, and your return values should also include generic types.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenSteenbeeke tips are always welcome, I am still a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your loop doesn't add the last group of consecutive seats if that group includes the last element of the `List`. You should add logic after your loop to add that last group:

```
for (Seat seat : newList) {
    if (seat.IsFree()) {
        if (startIndex < 0) {
            startIndex = index;
        }
        consecutiveLength ++;
    } else {
        consecutiveMap.put(startIndex + 1, consecutiveLength);
        if (consecutiveLength == n) {
            // Found, do something here
        }
        // Reset
        startIndex = -1;
        consecutiveLength = 0;
    }
    index++;
}
// added logic:
if (startIndex >= 0) {
    consecutiveMap.put(startIndex + 1, consecutiveLength);
}
return consecutiveMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `consecutiveMap.put` only exists within the `else` clause of your loop, and since the final element in your list is free, this code never gets executed for the final two seats.

1. `seat.IsFree() == true`, increment counter
2. `seat.IsFree() == true`, increment counter
3. `seat.isFree() == false`, add value to map, reset counter
4. `seat.isFree() == true`, increment counter
5. `seat.isFree() == true`, increment counter

Then the loop terminates, so the final counter is not added to your map.